# Printer independent way to preview and print generic text in Java

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextpane

I examined the possibilities of previewing and printing generic text in Java. The requirements which I depend on are:

1. I should be able to specify font family and size of the font for both the preview component and for printed text.
2. The print preview must look exactly the same as the printed text.
3. Printing must be independend of printer device (no printer specific commands to define fonts etc.).
4. Printing of approx. 20 pages of generic text must start immediately (without any significant delay caused by data processing)

To meet the aformentioned requirements I first tried the Java Print Service API. I created the JTextPane which contained the text to preview and print. By using JTextPane I was able to specify the font so the result looked fancy. To print data from JTextPane I used the standard procedure, which is independend from printer device

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
pj.setPrintable(myTextPane);
pj.print();
```

Everything would be fine if printing 20 pages of plain text wouldn't start in 15 seconds after the print() method was executed.

However printing starts immedialety when I print the same text as raw byte array ('application/octet-stream') with few PCL specific commands to set a proper font. But this approach is printer specific and there is also a problem with previewing the text so that the priview look exactly the same as printed text.

The problem with JTextPane is most likely caused by the fact that the data sent to printer are too large (pixel-by-pixel) while the second solution is a matter of few bytes. Unfortunately none of these solutions are sufficion for me because they don't meet all of the requirements.

Probably the solution would be if there is some 'facade' over printer control languages (PCL, ESC/P, ...) which would allow me to set the text font independently from the printer device. The problem with print preview would not be solved, but at least the printing would start immediately.

Any advice how to print the plain text not breaking the aforemention 4 criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The problems above seems to be linked to Linux print driver and Cups.
I tried to print some text on Windows and everything works fine. Printing even starts immediately.